# Expected statement error at Line 1 Char 1 for example script

Tags: vbscript

I'm completely new to scripting and am trying to mess around with it and start learning. I've done a couple `WScript.Echo` commands displaying a message or adding two numbers. I copied the below code from a MS article I was reading on the [`Echo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f603s7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

It seems it is having issues with `<package>`. Is this an unacceptable way to start a script? What else would I need to do to get this example code to work on my machine?

Also, can't get the code to post in my question. Indenting 4 spaces doesn't do anything.

Comment: *'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.'* See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Copy the code between, but not including `<script language="VBScript">` and `</script>`, paste into a new file, save as v.vbs execute with `wscript.exe x.vbs`

Comment: VBScript can be used for different things. Don't confuse VBS that is run as a client-side script in Internet Explorer with VBS that you can run on your Windows PC. The latter can't have `<...>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code in that article is for [`.wsf` files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gstemp/archive/2004/02/24/79183.aspx), not for `.vbs` files. If you want to use the latter: strip the XML tags from the sample code and it should work.

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oDrives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
Set oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections
WScript.Echo "Domain = " & WshNetwork.UserDomain
WScript.Echo "Computer Name = " & WshNetwork.ComputerName
WScript.Echo "User Name = " & WshNetwork.UserName
WScript.Echo 
WScript.Echo "Network drive mappings:"
For i = 0 to oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
  WScript.Echo "Drive " & oDrives.Item(i) & " = " & oDrives.Item(i+1)
Next
WScript.Echo 
WScript.Echo "Network printer mappings:"
For i = 0 to oPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
  WScript.Echo "Port " & oPrinters.Item(i) & " = " & oPrinters.Item(i+1)
Next
```